# Targeting the next td after the other td's class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<tr>
    <td>Full File</td>
    <td><span class="badge">5</span></td>
    <td><div class="progress"><div class="bar Full"></div></div></td>
    <td><span class="label ">Waiting</span></td>
</tr>
```

Hi all! 
Short and to the point:

I want to target, with jquery, the 'span.label'  knowing the class '.Full'

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('span.label');
```

Or

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('span.label');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('.Full').closest('tr').find('.label');
```

- Get the `Full` jQuery object first.
- Next go to the `closest` parent `tr` element.
- Then using `.find()` go to the specified span with class as `label`

**EDIT**

For specifically targeting the span with class `label` use:

```
$('.Full').closest('tr').find('span.label');
```

Comment: This is what I would use... suggested a minor edit since asker specified span.label.  There may be other label classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('div.Full').closest('td').next('td').children('span.label');
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) is faster than `.find()`